# Get the index where the hashset keyword matched in a string

Tags: java

eg:
I  have a string "i am working with hashset"
and one of my keywords in hashset is "with"

How can i get start and end index of the keyword that was found in the string in java.

Comment: Please, use Google first before asking... Googling for `java iterate hashset` yielded [How to Iterate over a Set/HashSet](http://beginnersbook.com/2014/08/how-to-iterate-over-a-sethashset/), and googling for `java find substring` yielded [Java - String indexOf() Method](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_indexof.htm)... Now put one and one together and you have it.

Comment: A Set doesn't have a concept of an index.  You can invent one but it is unlikely to be useful.

Comment: I think neither of you understood the question

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
Set<String> keywords = new HashSet<>();
keywords.add("with"); 
String input = "I am working with hashset";
for(String keyword : keywords) {
    int startIndex = input.indexOf(keyword);
    if (startIndex >= 0) {
        int endIndex = startIndex + keyword.length();
        System.out.printf("%s start:%s, end:%s%n", keyword, startIndex, endIndex);
    }
}
```

(untested)